# how come MySQL bit data type php print unicode?

Tags: php, javascript, json, extjs

When my MySQl Data Type is bit(1) ,but when printed with php `json_encode` will write with unicode? IIS are working fine,
 but in my dedicated server Apache hosting will become unicode. WHY?
[image]

you can see the `Locating`, `Locating` on Mysql data type is bit, but printed \u0001? why?

this is my coding GET method `get-googlemarker.php` to get this result

```
<?php
mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "123456") or die("Could not connect");
mysql_select_db("db_gps") or die("Could not select database");

$parent_id = $_GET['mainid'];

$query = "SELECT        *
FROM          tbl_locate AS a
INNER JOIN     
(
    SELECT    MainID, Max(DateTime) AS DateTime
    FROM      tbl_locate
    GROUP BY  MainID
) AS b
ON            a.MainID = b.MainID
AND           a.DateTime = b.DateTime
LEFT JOIN     
(
    SELECT b.PicData
     , b.PicUploadedDateTime
     , b.MainID
  FROM (SELECT    MainID,Max(PicUploadedDateTime) as PicUploadedDateTime
        FROM      tbl_picture
        group by MainID
       ) l
  JOIN tbl_picture b
    ON b.MainID = l.MainID AND b.PicUploadedDateTime = l.PicUploadedDateTime
) AS c
ON            a.MainID = c.MainID";

$rs = mysql_query($query);

$arr = array();
while($obj = mysql_fetch_object($rs)) {
 $arr[] = $obj;
}

echo json_encode($arr);


?>
```

### UPDATED

the representation data are correct, but the problem is when i m using below javascript i can't read the Locating value, 
i have tried `alert` the record, but is blank.i have tried Locating with `type:string` , `type:bit` , `type:bytes` , `type:int` ,
but does not work. can't show anything in `alert`

```
Ext.define('GoogleMarkerModel', {
        extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
        fields: [
        {name: 'ID',    type: 'int'},
        {name: 'Locating',    type: 'int'},
        {name: 'MainPower',    type: 'int'},
        {name: 'Acc',    type: 'int'},
        {name: 'PowerOff',    type: 'int'},
        {name: 'Alarm',    type: 'int'},
        {name: 'Speed',    type: 'int'},
        {name: 'Direction',    type: 'int'},
        {name: 'Latitude',    type: 'float'},
        {name: 'Longitude',    type: 'float'},
        {name: 'DateTime',    type: 'datetime'},
        {name: 'MainID',    type: 'int'},
        {name: 'IOState',    type: 'int'},
        {name: 'OilState',    type: 'int'},
        {name: 'PicUploadedDateTime',    type: 'datetime'},
        {name: 'PicData',    type: 'str'}
        ]
    });
```

Comment: you are storing the image in a db?

Comment: @Dagon Yes, i m , but i don't think so this is related with Question?

Comment: This is a valid JSON encoding for the binary value 0001. I see no error here. I wonder what 'IIS are working fine' means.

Comment: I just thought the `u` stands for `unsigned`.
When you want to use the variable with javascript it should work fine anyways. It's still the same datatype, just a different presentation.

Comment: IIS will return 0 or 1 only, but in Apache will return `\u0000` or `\u0001`

Comment: @JohnWalker how let apache return 0 without \u0000?php.ini httpd.conf how any config file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The presentation of the variable is still correct.

Since PHP 5.4, you can use the option `JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE` with `json_encode()`.
See http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

My guess is that your IIS is returning the unescaped value by default.

In Javascript you'd usually use `parseInt(\u0001)` or something.
Since it is extjs, I don't know for that.

**Plan B:**

A) Change the database column from bit to integer.

B) cast the database value in php

```
while($obj = mysql_fetch_object($rs)) {
  $obj->Locating = (int)$obj-Locating;
  // or try with (string) if (int) fails
  $arr[] = $obj;
}
```

C) simply `str_replace` in the json output:

```
$json = json_encode($arr);
$json = str_replace('"\u0001"', '"1"', $json);
$json = str_replace('"\u0000"', '"0"', $json);
```

Comment: `echo json_encode($arr,JSON_HEX_TAG | JSON_HEX_APOS | JSON_HEX_QUOT | JSON_HEX_AMP | JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);` Does not working...

Comment: I don't know,.. I think it's more of a JavaScript issue with the extjs model or smthing

Comment: NO, i use FIreBug to track php return, still return \u0001 value, how to change to return 0 and 1 only?

Comment: because \u0001 i can't store in my EXTJS JSstore

Comment: because i declare bit as string and storing \u0001 in string, i m trying to tracking out with `alert()` is blank. why?

Comment: Ask this in a different question pls. I provided you with another 3 different solutions.

Comment: here, this is another question link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18108760/extjs-jsonstore-bit-but-display-blank-value

Comment: dude. stop bothering me, you are  not supposed to be a programmer. become a forester instead.

Answer (score 0):

Use the mysqlnd (native driver) for php. If you're on ubuntu:

```
sudo apt-get install php5-mysqlnd
sudo service apache2 restart
```

The native driver returns integer types appropriately.

this method will only work for PDO (not mysqli).